# Can UI created in Rikulo be indexed by search engines?

Tags: search-engine, dart, rikulo

UI is created in Dart and the Dart code will be compiled to JavaScript. How to make them indexed by the search engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If UI is written in pure Dart, they won't be indexed. However, you can use [Rikulo EUL](https://github.com/rikulo/rikulo-eul), a markup language, to embed UI in the HTML page. Because EUL can be written as a HTML fragment, they will be indexed by the search engines.

For example, in the following code snippet, "Rich widgets", which is a label, will be indexed by search engines.

```
<div data-layout="type: linear">
   Rich widgets: <div class="Switch" data-value="true"/>
</div>
```

For a real example, please refer to [the Scroll View example](https://github.com/rikulo/rikulo-eul/tree/master/example/scroll-view).

Answer (score 5):

According to (http://www.forbes.com/sites/velocity/2010/06/25/google-isnt-just-reading-your-links-its-now-running-your-code/):

> On Friday, a Google spokesperson confirmed to Forbes that Google does
>   indeed go beyond mere “parsing” of JavaScript. “Google can parse and
>   understand some JavaScript,” said the spokesperson.

However, tomyeh's answer is good too :)